# zapier set bundle bundle inputData programatically

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

In my Zapier action I'm using 0Auth2 for authentication everything works fine, but I want to use some value coming from authentication test method while making other API calls, I was trying to pass it across by setting that value one of the variables in a bundle.inputData object but it is not working, I want to know if there is a way to achieve this.

result from testAuth method is something like this

```
{
 "name":"User name",
 "networkId" : 12
}
```

I want to use that networkId property in other API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

You can achieve this by adding an input field with `computed: true` and returning `networkId` from the `getAccessToken`.

There's more info in [these docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#computed-fields).

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Great! If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and mark it as correct ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: @xavdid, it will be helpful if you can explain with an example how to set computed value for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50386771/665961