# Zapier Cli - How to set value of computed inputField?

Tags: javascript, api, zapier, zapier-cli

I have a resource in my zapier cli app. In this resource's create specification, there are some inputFields, one of which is account_key (computed:true), the value of which I obtain during previous API call. My question is how can I set the account_key to a value I fetched previously?

```
create: {
        display: {
            label: 'Create Client',
            description: 'Creates a new client.',
        },
        operation: {
            inputFields: [
                {key: 'user_id', required: true, type: 'integer', label: 'User', dynamic: 'user.id.email'},
                {key: 'account_key', required: true, type: 'string', label: 'Account Key', computed:true},
                {key: 'address1', required: true, type: 'text', label: 'Address 1'}
            ],
            perform: createClient,
            sample: sample
        },
    },
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Computed fields are only used to capture output from OAuth and session output. Any computed fields in your auth definition will be available in `bundle.authData`. You shouldn't have an explicit field for reach in your actions.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: So, the question now becomes how can I send a hidden field data along inputFields?

Comment: You can't. it's either calculated at runtime (getting an account id by calling a `/me` method, it's available in the auth, or it's provided dynamically by the user